# different layout issue when using different browser in Dash

Tags: python, layout, browser, plotly-dash, dashboard

I use an external sheet for my Dash app and design my layout using multiple dropdown menus. When I open my application in Chrome, everything seems as intended. However, I see a completely different layout in Firefox. How can I preserve the same layout regardless of the browser used?

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(className="row", children=[
            html.Div(className='row', children=[
                html.Div(className='four columns', children=[

                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'North America', 'value': 'NA'},
                            {'label': 'Europe', 'value': 'EU'},
                            {'label': 'Asia', 'value': 'AS'}
                        ],
                        multi=True
                    )
                ]),
                html.Div(className='four columns', children=[
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'United States', 'value': 'USA'},
                            {'label': 'Canada', 'value': 'CAN'},
                            {'label': 'France', 'value': 'FRA'},
                            {'label': 'Germany', 'value': 'GER'},
                            {'label': 'China', 'value': 'CHN'},
                            {'label': 'India', 'value': 'IND'}
                        ],
                        multi=True
                    )
                ]),
                html.Div(className='four columns', children=[
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
                            {'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'MTL'},
                            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'},
                            {'label': 'London', 'value': 'LDN'},
                            {'label': 'Tokyo', 'value': 'TKY'},
                            {'label': 'Mumbai', 'value': 'MUM'}
                        ],
                        multi=True
                    )
                ])

            ]),

    ])
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In Chrome, this is how my app looks like initially.

[image]

Then, I use the same link in Firefox, all the drop down menus are organized top to bottom.

[image]